# A (cipher?) puzzle in a YouTube video description

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

So, by chance I stumbled upon this video: [MASTER BOOT RECORD - C:\DEFRAG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R77CC9D0sYI)
 that contains the following puzzle in the video description:

> 066 097 099 107 119 097 114 100 032 097 110 100 032 102 111 114 119 097 114 100 032 119 101 032 119 097 108 107 032 105 110 032 097 032 108 105 110 101 013 010 079 118 101 114 032 097 032 115 113 117 097 114 101 032 109 097 100 101 032 111 102 032 115 112 097 099 101 032 097 110 100 032 116 105 109 101 013 010 066 101 104 111 108 100 032 116 104 101 032 110 117 109 098 101 114 115 032 115 111 109 101 116 105 109 101 115 032 099 097 110 032 108 105 101 013 010 078 111 116 032 097 108 108 032 111 102 032 116 104 101 109 032 105 110 032 111 114 100 101 114 032 121 111 117 039 108 108 032 102 105 110 100 046 013 010 013 010 067 108 117 115 116 101 114 115 032 111 102 032 100 097 116 097 046 013 010 083 101 099 116 111 114 115 032 097 110 100 032 102 105 108 101 115 046 013 010 079 118 101 114 032 097 110 100 032 111 118 101 114 046 013 010 078 101 101 100 032 116 111 032 111 112 116 105 109 105 122 101 046 013 010 082 101 097 100 105 110 103 032 097 110 100 032 119 114 105 116 105 110 103 046 032 013 010 083 111 114 116 105 110 103 032 097 110 100 032 119 105 112 105 110 103 046 013 010 083 116 097 114 105 110 103 032 097 110 100 032 119 097 105 116 105 110 103 046 013 010 083 111 109 101 116 105 109 101 115 032 102 114 117 115 116 114 097 116 105 110 103 046 013 010 013 010 087 104 101 110 032 097 108 108 032 116 104 101 032 109 097 116 114 105 120 032 105 115 032 099 108 101 097 114 032 105 110 032 121 111 117 114 032 109 105 110 100 046 013 010 065 108 108 032 111 102 032 116 104 111 115 101 032 110 117 109 098 101 114 115 032 097 114 101 032 101 097 115 121 032 116 111 032 102 105 110 100 046 013 010 074 117 115 116 032 108 111 111 107 032 097 114 111 117 110 100 046 032 078 111 032 110 101 101 100 032 116 111 032 103 114 105 110 100 046 013 010 066 101 099 097 117 115 101 032 116 104 101 032 097 110 115 119 101 114 032 105 115 032 097 108 108 032 105 110 032 112 108 097 105 110 032 115 105 103 104 116 046 013 010 013 010 080 117 116 032 116 104 101 109 032 116 111 103 101 116 104 101 114 046 032 067 108 101 097 114 032 097 108 108 032 116 104 101 032 115 112 097 099 101 115 046 013 010 067 114 097 099 107 105 110 103 032 116 104 101 032 099 111 100 101 032 104 097 115 032 110 101 118 101 114 032 098 101 101 110 032 101 097 115 105 101 114 046 013 010 013 010 079 112 101 110 032 116 104 101 032 103 097 116 101 046 013 010 082 101 100 101 101 109 032 116 104 101 032 112 114 105 122 101 046 013 010 065 099 099 101 115 115 032 105 115 032 103 114 097 110 116 101 100 046 032 013 010 068 111 119 110 108 111 097 100 032 116 104 101 032 102 105 108 101 115 046
>
> Vg/pamR5uy5qKhUG2t+CYHyLsWGPHY0gjO9SKBkJA0ZWJyfGUrAzVQXZoqeSOXgO3Y+EaYr6g5iiQRN/EcW2DYUAMjm5Bx2+MwA1UkBB/7L2Nh8ZuviEsjWLyPK+hHcVdsiyeG47B8jE1p8Li4oR5jjPiNVNwTPxivW7i3HkmU+v+RLvIn2xSbxdzdi/hCQa5d7P3NDpJMePt5P4IN7o2w==

In chat, [Lukas Rotter provided the solution for the first part](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56001598#56001598):

> Backward and forward we walk in a line
> Over a square made of space and time
> Behold the numbers sometimes can lie
> Not all of them in order you'll find.
>
> Clusters of data.
> Sectors and files.
> Over and over.
> Need to optimize.
> Reading and writing.
> Sorting and wiping.
> Staring and waiting.
> Sometimes frustrating.
>
> When all the matrix is clear in your mind.
> All of those numbers are easy to find.
> Just look around. No need to grind.
> Because the answer is all in plain sight.
>
> Put them together. Clear all the spaces.
> Cracking the code has never been easier.
>
> Open the gate.
> Redeem the prize.
> Access is granted.
> Download the files.

I think that base64 might be involved in the solution of the second part, but a simple decoding leads to nothing.

Based on the video comments, I expect the solution to be a link of some sort, either to another youtube video (unlisted) or to a bandcamp or soundcloud file.

Additional hints:

- the video is [a still image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PqSM.jpg)
- the two songs contained in the video are
  [00:00] 01 CLUSTER 777
  [15:12] 02 CLUSTER 1337
- As correctly pointed out by  Anthony Ingram-Westover in the comments, there is a link to http://mbrserver.com/defrag/ where it is said that the second part is AES 256-bit, and there is [an additional image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yijrl.png) showing a Floppy Disk with some symbols (already present in the video/Album cover) and 4 numbers: (starting on the top left, reading clockwise) 36 34 30 32

Comment: The second part is AES 256, just need to figure out the key

Comment: Specifically, the youtube video links to the main website which says to solve the puzzle you will need a calculator, an AES 256 decrypter, and ASCII tables. It also has an image: http://mbrserver.com/defrag/disk.png That may be necessary to solve the puzzle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 1:

> Credit to [Lukas Rotter in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56001598#56001598), the initial step is to decode the
>  ASCII codes into text, e.g. using a tool such as the one found [here](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/), giving the following verses:
>
>  *Backward and forward we walk in a line
>
>  Over a square made of space and time
>
>  Behold the numbers sometimes can lie
>
>  Not all of them in order you'll find.
>
>
>
>  Clusters of data.
>
>  Sectors and files.
>
>  Over and over.
>
>  Need to optimize.
>
>  Reading and writing.
>
>  Sorting and wiping.
>
>  Staring and waiting.
>
>  Sometimes frustrating.
>
>
>
>  When all the matrix is clear in your mind.
>
>  All of those numbers are easy to find.
>
>  Just look around. No need to grind.
>
>  Because the answer is all in plain sight.
>
>
>
>  Put them together. Clear all the spaces.
>
>  Cracking the code has never been easier.
>
>
>
>  Open the gate.
>
>  Redeem the prize.
>
>  Access is granted.
>
>  Download the files.*

Step 2:

> Using the additional image of the [floppy disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yijrl.png), convert the numbers scratched into the disk to a magic number square, taking the numbers as the corners.
>   
> This is referred to in the poem: "Over a square made of space and time", as well as a reference to a "matrix". "Not all of them in order you'll find" refers to the fact that such squares are made up of a sequence of consecutive numbers rearranged to form a matrix.  
>  [image]

Step 3:

> This latin square has a unique solution, shown below:
>  [image]

Step 4:

> Follow the poem's instructions:
>
>  *When all the matrix is clear in your mind.
>
>  All of those numbers are easy to find.
>
>  Just look around. No need to grind.
>
>  Because the answer is all in plain sight.
>
>
>
>  Put them together. Clear all the spaces.
>
>  Cracking the code has never been easier.*
>
>  Extracting the digits from the image, putting them in a row left-to-right, top-to-bottom, and removing spaces, gives us the decryption key `362934313335323730`

Step 5:

> Using the AES decryption tool found [here](https://aesencryption.net/), we can decrypt the AES-256 part of the message using the decryption key above.
>
> **Text:** Vg/pamR5uy5qKhUG2t+CYHyLsWGPHY0gjO9SKBkJA0ZWJyfGUrAzVQXZoqeSOXgO3Y+EaYr6g5iiQRN/EcW2DYUAMjm5Bx2+MwA1UkBB/7L2Nh8ZuviEsjWLyPK+hHcVdsiyeG47B8jE1p8Li4oR5jjPiNVNwTPxivW7i3HkmU+v+RLvIn2xSbxdzdi/hCQa5d7P3NDpJMePt5P4IN7o2w==
>
> **Key:**
>  362934313335323730

This reveals the final message:

> Congratulations!
>
> Send an email to masterbootrecord@protonmail.com with subject MAGICSQUARE1337 to redeem your bonus prize.
>
> MASTER BOOT RECORD